# Magento admin catalog search finding results from search terms in any order

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have made an extension for the catalog search in the admin area of a Magento install to make the search results better.

If I had the following product title: "Logitech Wireless USB keyboard and mouse" and searched for "wireless mouse", the product would appear, however, if I search for "usb mouse keyboard" it would not, as they don't appear in that order. The code I have used for modifying the current search is below.

```
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column){

    $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();

    if ($column->getId() == "name" && isset($cond)) {

        $filterOrig = $cond['like'];
        $filterReplaced = str_replace(" ", "%", $filterOrig);
        $newZendDbExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr($filterReplaced);
        $modifCond = array('like'=>$newZendDbExpr);
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($column->getId() , $modifCond);

    }elseif ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
        $this->getCollection()->joinField('websites',
        'catalog/product_website',
        'website_id',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        null,
        'left');
    }else{
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    return $this;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through condition and add **like** for every term. I would have done something like this:

```
if ($column->getId() == "name" && isset($cond)) {

    $filtersOrig = explode(' ', $cond['like']);

    foreach ($filtersOrig as $filterOrig) {
        $filterReplaced = '%' . $filterOrig . '%';
        $newZendDbExpr = new Zend_Db_Expr($filterReplaced);
        $modifCond = array('like'=>$newZendDbExpr);
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($column->getId() , $modifCond);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That looks like it should work, but I have modified the code, and has not had an effect on the results. I have cleared cache etc. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Has anyone got any more ideas on this? The above doesn't seem to make a difference, although, it looks like it should.

Comment: This is something that I have already done for one of my projects and is working fine. The only difference is that I used `addAttributeToFilter()` because 'catalog/product' is **EAV** model. I corrected it in my post.